# Why simulation in YUI3 is not working?

Tags: jquery, yui, yui3

Hello I have very simple javascript like this.

```
YUI().use('node', 'node-event-simulate',function(Y){
var firstNameNode = Y.one('#firstNameId');
var lastNameNode = Y.one('#lastNameId');
var spanFirstNameNode = Y.one('#spanFirstNameId');

Y.use('event-focus', function () {
     firstNameNode.on('blur', function (e) {
       window.alert('hello');
       if( firstNameNode.get('value')=='')
        {
            spanFirstNameNode.set('text','empty first Name');
            value = spanFirstNameNode.get('text');
            window.alert("from");
        }
        else
        {
          spanFirstNameNode.set('text',' ');
        }
    });  

 });

     Y.one("#firstNameId").simulate("blur");  // **it is the simulation**

 })
```

I am trying to do some simulation. 
When I load the page in browser , I am not finding "blur" event is being triggered.

Any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try not using event-focus,  this is allows for the focus and blur synthetic events, which are useful for event delegation, which you are not doing.  As the documentation says:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html#no-synthetic-event-simulation-yet

event simulation does not work with synthetic events and, in this case, I don't think you need the synthetic version of it.